# How to use 'I learned that if I faced' in its reported-speech kind of context

Tags: past-tense, conditional-constructions, reported-speech

It is said that in reported speech, verbs tense will change. Also, when using 'if', verb tenses change. So what is the correct form of the below sentence?

> I learned that if I faced another question about designing a
>   structure, how I could use the formula.

Comment: It's nothing to do with "verb tenses" - just that you shouldn't be trying to include a "that- clause" here. *I learned **how** I could use the formula **if** I faced another question about designing a structure*. Alternatively you could simply remove the word ***how***, but that might subtly affect the meaning.

Comment: Nice suggestion. But I was curious how the original sentence should be altered to be grammatically accurate.

Comment: It depends on whether "using the formula" *automatically* enables you to face another question successfully, or whether it's specifically necessary that you should know ***how*** to use the formula.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how the sentence you provide is reported speech. Do you mean to change it so that it appears to be reported speech being quoted by a third party? If so, you are probably going to need to change 1st person to 3rd person.

> He said he learned, if he faced another question about designing a structure, how he could use the formula.

(I've used masculine pronouns, but it could be feminine).

As mentioned in the comments, the 'that' in the original sentence should be removed. The sentence as it stands is not grammatical.

It would probably be written best as:

> He said he learned how to use the formula if he faced another question about designing a structure.

Reported speech can be in the first person as well. In which case, you just need to add the words that make it clear you are dealing with reported speech: 'I said' at the start of the original sentence.